# Upload file on Server and Calculating Upload time

Tags: android, file-upload

I am working on an android application, in which we are required to upload an encrypted file to a server using VPN network on a mobile device. I have the method to encrypt the file, but I have no information how to upload a particular file to a remote server. Kindly suggest me some method to upload a particular file to the server. Also suggest me how to calculate the upload time.

Thanks!

Comment: files can be uploaded to server by using ftp programms ..

Comment: Yeah, I got to know how to upload a file but I don't know how to calculate the upload time. Could you please help me on that.

Comment: it depends on the server ..the speed can be found out by using the php code

Comment: Can you please specify the code which I have to write to upload a file?

Comment: you mean the php code ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code `$upload_time = time() - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];`.The result will be in seconds